# Filemaker Import Records GUI Blank After FM18 / FM18 Server Update

Tags: filemaker

Ever since the FMP 18 and FMS 18 server upgrade the import GUI has been changed and no shows no fields to map as if there is no columns in the table?

Anyone else experiencing this or know a fix?

[Import Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TqFJK.png)

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gxf7q.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filemaker have noted this has a bug but no fix yet,

Only solution is to edit the script on FMPA17 or below..

I had the same issue..

[Source](https://community.filemaker.com/en/s/question/0D50H00006o4Lb6SAE/fm18-scripted-import-order-is-blank-when-using-calculated-sql-query)